# Leaflet: from postgre via PHP to geojson to website

Tags: leaflet, geojson, pgrouting, php

I'm still looking for a best way to lunch pgrouting extension on my website as a rookie .Can anybody tell me is it possible? I have OSM data into postrgesql and want to do some routing machine. I want to run it in Leaflet with PHP. And my question is...can I run it as a geojson file? I heard that I can turn php file into geojson which can be lunched in Leaflet as a layer. Maybe some example? Tutorials? Someone need to head up me on the right way, becouse I'm confused after milion options that I have found in last few days.

Comment: What have you tried?  What happens when you try it?  Please [edit] your question to include details about your attempt and the result.  Include a sample of the data you're using, and any code attempt.